# NSComboBox Binding so it calls selectItematIndex instead of just displaying property value

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, restkit, cocoa-bindings, nscombobox

I have a NSCombobox that is binded to an Object Controller. The Object Controller is an instance of an (custom) **Employee Class** that is created via RestKit's object serialization framework. The NSComboBox's Value is binded to a key path **employeeType**, which is an int value stored on an remote MySql database. The int value corresponds to the employee type, so

```
0 == "Full Time" 
1 == "Part Time"
2 == "Terminated"
....
11 == "Temp Worker"
```

Currently (as expected), the NSComboBox displays the int value. Is there a way to invoke selectItemAtIndex: using that int value in IB so it selects the item at that index, not just putting the int value in the NSComboBox via bindings?

My thoughts were I could override the getter in a a property so it would look like:

```
if ([self employeeType] == 0) {
    [comboBox selectItemAtIndex:0];
}
```

But I don't believe this would be correct use of bindings.

Comment: Are the strings themselves ("Full TIme", Part Time", etc) available to the object controller?

Comment: Not yet, I simply populated the NSComboBox using Interface Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the pop-up button's "Selected Index" to your controller instead of "Selected Value". Here is a screen-shot to make things clearer:

[image: Interface Builder - Bindings]